# After I deployed my project with Jenkins,my $CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/{projectname}.xml was deleted

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

- $CATALINA_HOME is /usr/local/tomcat7
- $CATALINA_BASE is /home/www
- Deploy tool is Jenkins

I deploy my project by Jenkins,and it does work fine but one problem.
After I deployed my project with Jenkins,my $CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/{projectname}.xml was deleted which the file the database connection information are stored !!!
Maybe the file is automatically generated during deploying? And how I can do if I want the xml file to be generated automatically.

I wonder if there is anyone see those issues before, if there is, I really appreciate any solutions. Or, if you have other explanation and/or question for my case, you're welcome! Thanks

Comment: if you share your job config details it could help, if problem is a particular xml file getting deleted, take a backup before deployment and restore contents after deployment is sucessful

Comment: The deployment path of my project is $CATALINA_BASE/webapps.
The file that stores db connection information is placed $CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost，which is as follows

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context docBase="projectname" path="/projectname" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" logAbandoned="true" maxActive="10" maxIdle="3" name="jdbc/MasterDB" password="password" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" testOnBorrow="true" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://ip:port/master_db?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;autoReconnect=true" username="user" validationQuery="SELECT 1"/>
</Context>

Comment: Indeed,as you said,it's a way that restore contents after deployment is sucessful.But I don't think it's the fundamental way.Thanks for your advice.